# Claim type roles is missing in the access token when a HTTP POST call is made to https://login.microsoftonline.com/{{TenantID}}/oauth2/token

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, office365api

Folks!

I am a newbie to MS REST API and I am trying to access OneDrive via Microsoft Graph APIs. I have an enterprise office 365 account and here is what i have done so far :

1. Created an Azure App, exactly by following the steps mentioned here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/toolkit/get-started/add-aad-app-registration.
2. Added the following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/concepts/permissions_reference?view=odsp-graph-online ***Delegated*** API permissions.

Attaching a screenshot below:

[Graph API Permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YF1ts.png)

Firstly, executed the below REST API to acquire the access token :

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/<TenantId>/oauth2/token' \
--form 'grant_type=client_credentials' \
--form 'client_id=<ClientId>' \
--form 'client_secret=<ClientSecret>' \
--form 'resource=https://graph.microsoft.com/'
```

This returns the desired Access Token, HTTP response is as shown below :

```
{
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": "3599",
    "ext_expires_in": "3599",
    "expires_on": "1611896111",
    "not_before": "1611893123",
    "resource": "https://graph.microsoft.com/",
    "access_token": "eyJ..."
}
```

Now, i am trying a HTTP GET request to the below end-point `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<idOrUserPrincipalName>/drive`

```
curl --location --request GET 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<UserPrincipalName>/drive' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer eyJ...'
```

and i get a HTTP 403 (Forbidden) from the server with the below error message :

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "AccessDenied",
    "message": "Either scp or roles claim need to be present in the token.",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "2021-01-29T06:17:10",
      "request-id": "c1a6a642-5cf6-40ed-bf55-75c1e3845357",
      "client-request-id": "c1a6a642-5cf6-40ed-bf55-75c1e3845357"
    }
  }
}
```

Upon closely examining the JWT token and de-coding it, I see that the roles claim is missing from it.

```
{
  "typ": "JWT",
  "nonce": "HKO...",
  "alg": "RS256",
  "x5t": "nOo...",
  "kid": "nOo..."
}.{
  "aud": "https://graph.microsoft.com/",
  "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/.../",
  "iat": 1611893058,
  "nbf": 1611893058,
  "exp": 1611896958,
  "aio": "E2Z...",
  "app_displayname": "OneDrive_API_Test",
  "appid": "085...",
  "appidacr": "1",
  "idp": "https://sts.windows.net/.../",
  "idtyp": "app",
  "oid": "a5c...",
  "rh": "0.AAA...",
  "sub": "a5c...",
  "tenant_region_scope": "NA",
  "tid": "...",
  "uti": "Bf...",
  "ver": "1.0",
  "xms_tcdt": 1394468532
}.[Signature]
```

Ideally it should look something like this :

```
{
  "typ": "JWT",
  "nonce": "toS...",
  "alg": "RS256",
  "x5t": "nOo...",
  "kid": "nOo..."
}.{
  "aud": "https://graph.microsoft.com",
  "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/.../",
  "iat": 1611766631,
  "nbf": 1611766631,
  "exp": 1611770531,
  "aio": "E2J...",
  "app_displayname": "myapp",
  "appid": "a5c...",
  "appidacr": "1",
  "idp": "https://sts.windows.net/.../",
  "idtyp": "app",
  "oid": "215...",
  "rh": "0.AAAA...",
  "roles": [
    "User.ReadWrite.All",
    "Files.ReadWrite.All",
    "User.Read.All",
  ],
  "sub": "215...",
  "tenant_region_scope": "NA",
  "tid": "b39...",
  "uti": "aKV...",
  "ver": "1.0",
  "xms_tcdt": 1394468532
}.[Signature]
```

Could someone let me if i have misconfigured something in my application, thus missing the roles claim, which is leading to the 403 error? Any pointers would be super helpful

Comment: You need to add application permissions as you are using APP token here.

Comment: If my answer is helpful, please accept it is that it can be helpful to other who have this same question. See   https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

If you are using client credential flow you will be getting an APP token and the request with payload looks something like this.

`POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token`

Request body:

client_id=535fb089-9ff3-47b6-9bfb-4f1264799865
&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default
&client_secret=qWgdYAmab0YSkuL1qKv5bPX
&grant_type=client_credentials

In Azure AD app registration you need to add Application permissions. Here as you are calling /users/userid/drive you need to have at least `Files.Read.All` application permission.

Now make the Graph API call with curl as you did with this access token. You will get the data

Comment: So, the Microsoft admin working in my organization specifically asked me to add Delegated permission and not App permission. Do you know how i can get this working with the set of delegated permissions? Are there different set of API's that needs to be executed? I would appreciate, If you could point me to the right documentation/examples, if any

Comment: If you want to use delegated permission then the user login is required. You should implement [authorization code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) and get the token and call MS Graph as `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive` which gets the drive details of the loggedin user.

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by user login is required? Do i have to pass the user name and password the the above request? FYI, we are using a Federated identity and i am not sure if this is supported. Also, i went through the documentation that you have mentioned in this link and i could not really understand the how i could get most of the parameters for the request (except for a few obvious ones). Is there a sample CURL or a Postman sample that i can try?

Answer (score 0):

@Shiva Keshav Varma answered very well. I will explain your doubts:

> 1. Why does your token have no roles claim?

The `roles` claim only shows **application permissions**, because you have granted **delegated permissions** to the application, so there is no such claim in your token.

> 2. What is the difference between `/me` endpoint and `/users` endpoint?

The `/me` endpoint usually requires user interaction. At this time, the application representative executes the request as a logged-in user. It requires you to grant delegation permissions to the application, and then use the [auth code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) to obtain an access token, and the flow supports federated authentication and MFA. When you parse the token you will see the `scp` claim.

The `/users` endpoint is usually used in daemons that do not require user interaction. It requires you to grant application permissions to the application, and then use the [client credential flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) to obtain an access token. When you parse the token, you will see the `roles` claim.

Finally, make a summary: According to your requirements, if you can only grant delegated permissions, then you should use **auth code flow** to obtain an access token, and then call the /me endpoint: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive`.

There are two steps to obtain a token using auth code flow:

1. Get the authorization code in the browser, which requires you to log  user.

   Enter this url in the browser to get the authorization code:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxx-bd27-40d5-8459-230ba2a757fb/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=f212af58-f976-4bc5-be9d-7aexxxxxxxx
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://localhost:4500/web/completeoauth/ms
&response_mode=fragment
&scope=Files.Read.All
&state=12345
```

[image]

2. Use the authorization code to redeem the access token in postman.

[image]